# Write a C program that will display a name on the screen fifteen times

Tags: c

I want to write a C program that will display a name on the screen fifteen times.  The program does not allow a loop.  No WHILE, No DO WHILE, and No FOR LOOPS.  You can only have one printf statement within the code.  The output will look as follows:

1. Cake
2. Cake
3. Cake
4. Cake
5. Cake
6. Cake
7. Cake
8. Cake
9. Cake
10. Cake
11. Cake
12. Cake
13. Cake
14. Cake
15. Cake

I do not how to do it. Please help.

thanks

Comment: So you want to write a C program with CSS?

Comment: css and c? How come is this possible.!!??? :P

Comment: No, I want  write a c Program with c++. I use visual studio

Comment: I guess Close Vote Options changed again, but I've voted to close your question as you don't show a minimal understanding of the problem being solved, nor relevant code is provided

Comment: removed `css` tag for this post!

Comment: printf('1.cake\n2.cake\n.....');

Comment: Why would you not use any loops ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the stipulation "only one printf statement" only constrain number of printf, or does it mean that is the only statement you can use? Assuming the former:

```
void print(int num)
{
    printf("%d. Cake\n", num);
    if (num == 15)
        return;
    else
        print(num+1);
}

int main()
{
    print(1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
printf('1.cake\n2.cake\n......');
```

this will be the solution in no `loops` are allowed and a single `printf` statement should do.

Comment: I guess this is exactly what the asker wants.. :)